# To open this page in IE mode, try restarting Microsoft Edge. - Keep Getting That

Tags: microsoft-edge

Some computer wich run Win 10 SO - 21h2 keep getting, as title says:

```
To open this page in IE mode, try restarting Microsoft Edge.
```

I have restarting and reinstall edge, but the issues continues, any help please.

Comment: Do other computers work with Edge?  Is it just this one computer?

Comment: that particular computer,
The others computers where I have testes as not win 10 21h2.

Answer (score 0):

Edge for Windows 10 V21H2 should work. I have used that when V21H2 was current.

In the repairs I suggest below, (2) and (3) will bring the computer to V22H2.  You might try updating first before trying the repairs below.

Try following repairs:

**(1) DISM / SFC.**   Sometimes works but only average rate of success.

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(2) Windows 10 Repair Install.**   Fixes many issues.  Use the Keep Everything option.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(3)** If the first 2 do not work, the damage is more serious and / or there is Windows User Profile damage.

In either case, back everything up and reinstall Windows 10 fresh.

Comment: (1) DISM / SFC
not working,
(2) Windows 10 Repair Install - remotely working deploy. not possible. any ideia please?

Comment: It would appear to me that since DISM is not working and apparently the computer is not updating that you now need to reinstall Windows.  You should be able to initiate a Windows Reset remotely,